# What are these Elasticsearch indices used for?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I safely delete the following indices? Or are these needed for something?

```
.monitoring-es-6-2018.06.08
.security-6
.monitoring-alerts-6
.watches
.triggered_watches
.watcher-history-7-2018.06.08
```

Answer (score 0):

You think them as the logs of elasticsearch. 
For example, .watcher-history has all the records for what watches runs and their result

The other indices listed above has similar functionality. They are used for debugging